# Why Isnt TwitchTv Streaming Working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, streaming

I just updated to 1.7.4 and connected my Twitch account to my Mojang account.  When I finally tried to stream it worked for a few seconds and then this came up in chat:
[image]

This stopped the stream from running.  I have tried lowering the quality and FPS to 20 but that doesn't help.  I want to know how to fix this problem.  If you want to know my computer specs let me know.

Comment: you should reduce the framebuffer or the bitrate. which program are you using?

Comment: @Wandang I think he's using Minecraft.

Comment: if minecraft can stream without third party software then minecraft should have an option for buffer and/or bitrate. otherwise the problem lies in minecrafts code / mojang. http://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/ttv-ec-queue-too-long-and-ttv-submitframe-callback/135

Comment: If he was using Minecraft to stream, wouldn't it show that he was streaming in the corner?

Comment: @NovaSword it would unless the issue stopped the streaming.

Comment: furthermore you should post your specs and bandwith

Comment: @3ventic I can confirm that this issue stops your broadcast. I figured it meant my connection was crapping out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a thread](http://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/ttv-ec-queue-too-long-and-ttv-submitframe-callback/135) in the Twitch forums:

> Note that TTV_EC_QUEUE_TOO_LONG means the network queue is too long,
>   which means the bitrate that the user set is not being sustained by
>   their upload.

Try lowering your bitrate to something more reasonable, preferably something much lower than 1024 Kbps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to options/broadcast settings/bandwidth and turn it all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Broadcast Settings in options (ON pause), then turn bandwidth too the lowest it can get.